# Is there a way to create a user with username "admin"?

Tags: administration

Is there a way to create a user with username `admin`?

When I tried to pick a username `admin` I got this error/ warning message.

> The username you entered (admin) is reserved for use by the system.
>   Please select a different one.

[image]

Please note that I have gone through this Q [How to add an user called "admin"](https://askubuntu.com/q/837537/739431), this Q is about creating a user with username `admin` after successful Installation.

My Q is about creating a user with username `admin` at Installation time itself.

Thoughts: If there is a way to Customize the ISO with tool/tools like CUBIC https://launchpad.net/cubic to alter the name in the error/ warning message?

Workarounds are welcome.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/900986/295286 Related question but not duplicate

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group/122500#122500 and it comes from Debian as a extra Ubuntu rule: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=450954   "admin" is no longer used but still on the reserved names list. (we now use `sudo` as a user/group).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just comment out `admin` in the list of reserved usernames before launching the installer. You don't need to remaster the ISO for this, though you could if you wanted.

The graphical installer on the desktop ISOs for Ubuntu and most of its official derivatives is [Ubiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_(software)). This is the installer pictured in the screenshot shown in your question. It keeps a list of reserved usernames in `/usr/lib/ubiquity/user-setup/reserved-usernames`.

Boot from a live USB or live DVD. Select the option to try Ubuntu, rather than the option to install it, since you should modify that file before running the installer.

Then comment out the `admin` line in that file by placing `#` at the front of the line. One way to do this is to run this one command:

```bash
sudo sed -i.orig 's/^admin$/# &/' /usr/lib/ubiquity/user-setup/reserved-usernames
```

*Or*, if you prefer, you can open the file in a text editor and manually make and save your changes:

```bash
sudoedit /usr/lib/ubiquity/user-setup/reserved-usernames
```

After modifying the file, double-click on the icon on the desktop to install Ubuntu.

I've tested this with the Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (amd64) desktop image.

If you feel like remastering the ISO image to avoid having to do that, you can. Any of the popular methods should work, since you're just changing one file inside the squashfs image. But if you only need this for a handful of installations, it's probably not worth it, since you can just run that one `sed` command (or equivalent) each time before launching the installer.

---

When you use this method, an `admin` group will be created and it will be used as the `admin` user's primary group. The `admin` user's UID will be 1000, and the `admin` group's GID will be 1000 as well. I don't think you need to change this, but it's a good idea to be aware of its significance.

I presume you intend the user you create during installation and name `admin` to be an administrator of the system who is permitted to run arbitrary commands as root (or any user) with `sudo`. So it shouldn't be a problem that Ubuntu's `/etc/sudoers` still confers those privileges to members of the `admin` group as well as the `sudo` group, even though membership in the `admin` group is no longer a common or recommended way to give a user these privileges.

Ubuntu's default `/etc/sudoers` contains these lines:

```bash
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

You could comment out the `%admin` line if you wanted. Run `sudo visudo` to edit the file. But you really don't need to.

---

Even though it's easy to make the installer let you proceed with the username `admin`, I encourage you to consider the workaround of *just not making a user called that*, for two reasons:

1. Creating a user called `admin` on Ubuntu, especially during installation, is not tested. In my limited testing, it doesn't seem to cause any problems, but I can't be sure it doesn't trigger or exacerbate any current or future bugs.
2. `admin` is an easily guessed username. When examining the logs of Internet-facing SSH servers, I've noticed that `admin` is one of the nonexistent users that receive a high volume of automated illicit login attempts.

   It's often not necessary or worthwhile to keep usernames *secret*. But `admin` is both easily guessed and attractive-sounding to people who want to break into your system.

   Of course, some usernames, like `root`, are even more ubiquitous and attractive. This is why allowing root logins is discouraged, especially password-based logins.

If your motivation for using the name `admin` is that this username is hidden in some utilities or display managers, it's likely you can configure them to hide another name.

With that said, so long as you otherwise follow good security practices, including the use of strong passwords, I wouldn't expect any problems.

Comment: @PRATAP I hope it helps! Although I've covered the topic at some length, the actual instructions for how to do it are near the top of the answer. (I do suggest reading the rest though, since I try to cover some of the possible ramifications of having a user called `admin`.)

Comment: @PRATAP That looks fine to me.

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, that's what it looked like when I installed 18.04 to test this. I considered including screenshots in this post, but I decided against it, because when Ubiquity rejects `admin` (that is, when one does not modify `/usr/lib/ubiquity/user-setup/reserved-usernames`), it does so only when one tries to click continue on [that screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkwq5.jpg), rather than immediately once `admin` is typed in. Anyway, it looks like this worked for you--I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do so at installation time itself, but assuming the link above works (creating a user with username "admin" after successful installation), one workaround could be installing with a dummy username, add a user named "admin" after installation, and then removing your dummy user. Hope that helps!